# use value from method call on Enum as annotation parameter

Tags: java, enums, annotations

I have

```
enum Operations { 
 OPERATION_NAME("operation/path");    
    private final String path;

    Operations(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String path() {
        return path;
    }
}
```

I would like to use value of path on annotations on my REST API methods

```
  @Path(Operations.OPERATION_NAME.path())
  void operation() {
  }
```

but java compiler complains

> Attribute value must be constant

Is there a way to resolve that in java8?

I know I could have one enum with operation names and bunch of static String fields with paths (static Strings can be used as attribute in @Path annotation) but I do not like this approach.

Comment: Annotation attribute value must be evaluated at compile time, while an `enum` instance can be evaluated only at run time.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto not `enum` but method. `Enum` can be used as parameter of annotation

Comment: Instances cannot be evaluated at compile-time, as the reference to them created at class loading...

Comment: A bunch of static String fields with paths is the way to go.

Comment: BTW What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I want to have use enum with method names in one place, and path in another place (client calls in tests, @Path annotations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use enum methods in annotation parameter, but you can create class:

```
public final class Operations {

    private Operations() {};

    public static final String op1 = "operation/path";
    public static final String op2 = "operation2/path";

    public enum Enum { 

        OPERATION1(op1),
        OPERATION2(op2);

        private final String path;

        Enum(final String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        public final String path() {
            return path;
        }
    }

}
```

There will be not duplication, and you can still use your enum same as before, and `static String` literals in annotatios

Comment: OP wrote they do not like the `static` field approach within the `enum`... Why do you think they would like it in a separate `class`, that is hiding the `enum` inside itself?

Comment: Not perfect, but it seems it is no better option. I cannot get to operation name as method call on enum. I must have static String. So now, at least I see that all those static strings are used (in operation enums)

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I just provide a way how to connect enum with `static string` fields. There is no better way